# Flux of Lorentz trasformation in spacetime, infinitesimal generator

Tags: matrices, lie-algebras, physics, general-relativity

I'm considering the following matrixs which I know that they form a flux of Lorentz trasformation in spacetime.

I want to know how to calculate the infinitesimal generator of this flux. Unfortunately I have no particular knowledge of Lie algebra for this reason I need an explanation that does not assume the whole knowledge of it.

$$\begin{pmatrix}
\frac{4- \cos(\rho)}{3} & \frac{2- 2\cos(\rho)}{3} & 0 & -\frac{\sin(\rho)}{\sqrt{3}} \\
\frac{2\cos(\rho) - 2}{3} & \frac{4- \cos(\rho)}{3} & 0 & \frac{2\sin(\rho)}{\sqrt{3}}\\ 
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
-\frac{\sin(\rho)}{\sqrt{3}} & -\frac{2\sin(\rho)}{\sqrt{3}} & 0 & \cos(\rho) \\
\end{pmatrix}$$

Thank you so much for your help

Comment: I think you may have made a mistake writing this down. For the second row, second column, I think it should be: $\frac{4 \cos(\rho)-1}{3}$. In that case I can help you with your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, for a one-parameter group of operators $A(\rho)$, it's infinitesimal generator is just $A'(0)$. So, if I understood the question correctly, the infinitesimal generator is

$$\begin{pmatrix}
-{1\over 3} && -{2 \over 3} && 0 && 0 \\
{2\over 3} && -{1 \over 3} && 0 && 0 \\
0 && 0 && 0 && 0 \\
0 && 0 && 0 && 1 \\
\end{pmatrix}$$

Answer (score 1):

See my comment, in that case:
Do this kind of problem by writing this matrix as a sum of two matrices as follows:$$
W(\rho) = \left(\begin{array}{cccc}
\frac{4- \cos(\rho)}{3} & \frac{2- 2\cos(\rho)}{3} & 0 & -\frac{\sin(\rho)}{\sqrt{3}} \\
\frac{2\cos(\rho) - 2}{3} & \frac{4\cos(\rho)-1}{3} & 0 & \frac{2\sin(\rho)}{\sqrt{3}}\\ 
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
-\frac{\sin(\rho)}{\sqrt{3}} & -\frac{2\sin(\rho)}{\sqrt{3}} & 0 & \cos(\rho) \\
\end{array}\right) = \\
\begin{pmatrix}
\frac{4-\cos(\rho)}{3} & \frac{2-2\cos(\rho)}{3} & 0 & 0 \\
\frac{2\cos(\rho) - 2}{3} & \frac{4\cos(\rho)-1}{3} & 0 & 0\\ 
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & \cos(\rho) \\
\end{pmatrix}
- \sin(\rho)\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 & 0 & \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}} \\
0 & 0 & 0 & -\frac{2}{\sqrt{3}}\\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}} & \frac{2}{\sqrt{3}} & 0 & 0 \\
\end{pmatrix}
$$
Where I have explicitly pulled out the $\sin$ dependence. Now look at the matrix $$ u =\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 & 0 & \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}} \\
0 & 0 & 0 & -\frac{2}{\sqrt{3}}\\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}} & \frac{2}{\sqrt{3}} & 0 & 0 \\
\end{pmatrix}$$ Notice that $u^3 = -u$ so that in particular, this matrix is easy to exponentiate. In fact Exp$(u) = W(1)$ is your original matrix evaluated at $\rho = 1$ so then you can prove $$\textrm{Exp}( \rho  u) = W(\rho)$$ If memory serves me, in physics land they call $u$ the infinitesimal generator of $W$. But check with your instructor.